# How to set image of an RepositoryItemProgressBar

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, devexpress

How can we set image of an RepositoryItemProgressBar, i tried setting the Appearance.Image property and set the Appearance.Options.UseImage property to true.

Comment: Why do you want to set at picture in there? why not use a PictureEdit?

Comment: You can post here your requirements, So, user can suggest you better way to achieve your goal.. BTW, you can draw image on it on it's paint event....